# How to set position for imageView animated with timer when "imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, timer, autolayout

I have checked all over for a solution to one problem:
I have set an imageView to move with a timer, but I have another timer counting seconds, and every time the second-timer goes off, the imageView spawns in it's original position.

Here is the post where I found my solution:
[Swift: timer resetting the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29961767/swift-timer-resetting-the-view)

Here it suggests that I use "imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true", which actually works fine. But I have one problem. If I can't use Auto Layout, how do I tell the imageView where to spawn when the timer hasn't begun?

Because "imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true" basically kills my Auto Layouts, so it spawns about 30-40 pixels away from the middle, which it is set to do.

I don't find any use in showing my code, since it has got to do with the "imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true" command.

Comment: share your code that you've tried... so can help you..